# Функция mail()

Tags: php

Возможно ли использование функции mail() для отправки сообщений в локальном сервере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Необходимо настроить [сервер](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Local_Mail_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm).

Comment: Вот тут действительно спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

можно, главное чтоб адрес получателя существовал и сама функция отрабатывала без ошибки (насколько я понял Вы хотите на своей локальной рабочей машине отправлять почту, тогда у Вас должен быть настроен на локальной машине еще почтовый сервис, что нибудь типа sendmail)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже задавался этим вопросом, пока не наткнулся на программу CourierMS. Это небольшой почтовый сервис для отправки писем с сервера. Найти ее можно через любой поисковик. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

*скорее всего я не прав, но на всякий случай.*

---

возможно топикстартер имеет проблемы с тем что не отправляются сообщения на запущенном denwer. Дело в том что на денвере стоит заглушка что бы такого не делать.

Comment: Нет, денвером я не пользуюсь, но спасибо за ответ...